# Error en Stored Procedure en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando realizar un stored procedure en `mysql` y me marca un error solo que no se que es lo que este equivocado.

**Mi stored procedure es el siguiente:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inserstarHistorial
(IN inicio INT,IN fin INT)
BEGIN
    WHILE (fin>inicio) DO           
        INSERT INTO historial_academico (id_historial_academico, alumno_id_alumno) VALUES (inicio, inicio);
        SET inicio = inicio+1;
    END WHILE 
END
```

El error que me aparece, es el siguiente:

> `#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 5.`

Comment: ¿Ese `SET` a que función pertenece?